# Make pyenv build python with different sqlite version

Tags: python, installation, pyenv, building

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 and python version installed there is '3.10.4' while sqlite version is '3.37.2'. I need to use python '3.9.5' and sqlite '3.31.1' because the server that my code will live uses that.

Using pyenv fixes the problem for python but the sqlite one didn't. So I resort on building the sqlite from the source and try to link on pyenv install.

Basically this is what I tried to do:

```bash
~$ mkdir -p ~/usrapps/src
~$ cd ~/usrapps/src/
~/usrapps/src$ wget https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz
~/usrapps/src$ tar xvvf sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz 
~/usrapps/src$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3310100/
~/usrapps/src/sqlite-autoconf-3310100$ mkdir -p ~/usrapps/sqlite3311
~/usrapps/src/sqlite-autoconf-3310100$ ./configure --prefix=/home/paulo/usrapps/sqlite3311
~/usrapps/src/sqlite-autoconf-3310100$ make
~/usrapps/src/sqlite-autoconf-3310100$ make install
~/usrapps/src/sqlite-autoconf-3310100$ cd ~/
```

[Here's the full terminal ouput](https://gist.github.com/paulo-lucero/94a57545209d033d727f688c8137a377)

Now for installation of python 3.9.5, I do this different scenarios but first, `brew-pyenv-i` is aliased to `CC="$(brew --prefix gcc)/bin/gcc-12" pyenv install` the reason is I encounter a issue where installing python result to "BUILD FAILED: Mising OpenSSL" even though I have openssl install. Doing this fixed my issue, here's the [reference](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2293).

I uninstall first python(installed by pyenv) before each scenarios.

scenario 1 - [log](https://gist.github.com/paulo-lucero/9a6f486394810eecc4eac8b603c16d2b):

```bash
~$ LDFLAGS="-L/home/paulo/usrapps/sqlite3311/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/home/paulo/usrapps/sqlite3311/include" brew-pyenv-i 3.9.5
```

scenario 2 - [log](https://gist.github.com/paulo-lucero/c33d72ae433757baf7f0fa864f02313d):

```bash
~$ PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="LD_RUN_PATH=/home/paulo/usrapps/sqlite3311/lib LDFLAGS=-L/home/paulo/usrapps/sqlite3311/lib" brew-pyenv-i 3.9.5
```

scenario 3 - [log](https://gist.github.com/paulo-lucero/977d5b8028cc6be19ac12db662f61ff7):

```bash
~$ PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="LD_RUN_PATH=/home/paulo/usrapps/sqlite3311/lib LDFLAGS=-L/home/paulo/usrapps/sqlite3311/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/home/paulo/usrapps/sqlite3311/include" brew-pyenv-i 3.9.5
```

All attempts are successfully installed the python 3.9.5, but when I try check the sqlite version, its still same, not '3.31.1'

```bash
~$ pyenv shell 3.9.5
~$ python
Python 3.9.5 (default, Aug 26 2022, 08:45:14) 
[GCC 12.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.37.2'
```

I would like to avoid using `pysqlite3`, because that's mean I have to rewrite some of my code and my goal is not really to use multiple versions of sqlite in my app.

Comment: https://github.com/cLupus/asdf-sqlite
Try `asdf` it can help you to manage both python and sqlite

Comment: First of all, this question has very little to do, if at all, with either SQLite or bash. These tags should be removed. Secondly, when your code expects SQLite 3.31 and you get 3.37, that should not be a problem. SQLite developers take backward compatibility very seriously. If you are concerned about specific features, you need to cover them with appropriate functional tests, which would verify that you get the same behavior.

Comment: @PChemGuy I did some tests and I notice that `UPDATE FROM` is not supported at  '3.31.1' only at '3.33.0' & on wards which my code has one thus causing errors. Maybe you're right I should just do more testing because doing this causing me to much time.

Comment: Your question is about backward compatibility, not forward. Of course, new features are added to SQLite. So if you use one of such features, you will not be able to use an older copy. But the other way around is almost always fine with SQLite. You might be able to swap a much older version with a newer one without breaking the code.